# Filter in SQL on distinct values after grouping

Tags: sql, group-by, distinct

I have a dataset like

```
col1       col2       col3
A          x          1
A          x          2
A          x          3
B          y          4
B          -y         5
B          y          6
C          -z         7
C          z          8
C          -z         9
D          t          10
D          t          11
D          t          12
```

how can i pick out just the groups from col1 that have distinct values in col2? So A,D in this case.

something like

```
select * from table t1
where (select count(distinct col2)
       from table t2
       where t1.col1 = t2.col1) > 1
```

but more optimized?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you need is the column `col1` you can `group by col1` and set the condition in the HAVING clause:

```
SELECT col1
FROM tablename
GROUP BY col1
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT col2) = 1;
```

If you want all the rows from the table use the above query with the operator `IN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename 
WHERE col1 IN (
  SELECT col1
  FROM tablename
  GROUP BY col1
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT col2) = 1
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select col1
from t
group by col1
having min(col2) <> max(col2);
```

Comment: If OP wants instances where col2 has distinct values, shouldn't it be `min(col2) = max(col2)`?

Comment: @Andrew. . .  "distinct values" would mean the values are not unique -- at least how I read the question.